# Clear iPhone GPS coordinate cache to test poor GPS conditions?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, core-location

Once an iOS device has acquired a GPS fix, it will cache that coordinate for quite some time, and return that coordinate immediately as soon as you send CLLocationManager a startUpdatingLocation message.

This makes it impossible to test the behavior of GPS-related code under a poor GPS condition in an even remotely reproducible fashion. Particularly, the scenario where a phone cannot acquire a fix and never calls locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: simply can't be tested.

Powering down the device does not clear the GPS cache.

How can I clear the GPS cache, and thus reproducibly test how my app behaves under a poor GPS scenario for real users in real situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPS cache can be found here: /var/root/Library/Caches/locationd
You could use [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/) or [DiskAid for Mac](http://download.cnet.com/DiskAid/3000-18546_4-10860863.html) to reach and delete the folder.

Regarding the larger problem of validating GPS data you might want to read [Detecting Bad CoreLocation Data](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/02/detecting-bad-corelocation-data/). He offers a helper method to validate location data.  Good luck and hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Note that I do need to restart the phone after deleting the data in order for it to work, but it does work. This led me to dig up how to stop/start the locationd service itself, so now I'm doing this from an SSH shell on a jailbroken iPhone to help test real life GPS scenarios: `launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locationd.plist; rm -rf /var/root/Library/Caches/locationd/; launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locationd.plist`

This has already allowed me to find a UX problem with my app regarding the gps permission popup. :)